# Full screen Background on some part of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

i am trying to do a background on almost 75% of the whole page. I do not want the background on body as there is a solid color area on left hand side in design.

http://take.ms/uNp67

And if i put the background on the main-container, then it is not full screen from right hand side.

any clue on getting this done? I am using bootstrap

**Solution**: the position of bg should be recalculated .

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

function recenter(){
    $pos = $('.container').offset().left;
    $loc = $pos+300;

    $('body').css('background-position-x', $loc + "px");
}
recenter();
$(window).resize(function(){ recenter(); });
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you tried wrapping the right-side elements and then give the wrapper a background? I think it will work.

Comment: right side elements will still stay in the container, which is 9 columns and left side ( navigation ) is 3 column.  I need the bg on the area which is out of 12 columns ( container). to cover full screen on right hand side

Comment: @brainHax Can you change your structure to make it happen. Like make the left solid area separate `div` of 2 columns, then navigation of 3 and then right side content 7 colums.

Comment: @brainHax if you provide a jsfiddle (or your code) it would be helpful. Without code its hard to guess how you want things to happen.

Comment: please see this . https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8782/  .. did you think i had a fluid-container  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property.
To make it work on every device, use media-queries and reset position for each bootstrap breakpoint.

```
body {
    background-position: 100px 0;
    background-image: url(http://stylonica.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Beauty-of-nature-random-4884759-1280-800.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        background-position: 150px 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background-position: 100px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this, it does not work well on different screens.
this is what happens on browser re-size

http://take.ms/nEuAo

Comment: see my answer updated. I think this should help you.

Comment: Media query 1200px works fine on my desktop, but when i view the html on laptop it looks like this . ( on my laptop 1200px media query is applied )
http://take.ms/nFFph

Comment: another solution for you will be calculating xoffset with javascript of the main-container and apply this value to the background-position on every window resize.